# Get total days and Hours between 2 timestamps with excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

using excel 2013

I'm trying to get the total days and hours between current date/time and time stamp

using =NOW()-B3

And custom format
dd"-Days" hh"-hrs"

which gets me.

21/05/2015 12:45    00-days - 00-Hours

01/04/2015 13:23    18-days - 23-Hours

02/05/2015 13:45    18-days - 23-Hours

This is fine until a month is rolled over which will then give a wrong result. line 2 example. How do I get it to show total days.

many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use the `DATEDIF` function:

```
=DATEDIF(B3, NOW(), "d")
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't support hours AFAIK, so you have to combine it with your solution in order to get a combination of days and hours.

Answer (score 0):

Try this... assuming your first example is written in A1:

```
=ROUNDDOWN(C1,0)&"-days "&TEXT(C1-ROUNDDOWN(C1,0),"hh")&"-hours"
```

oh yeah... use a regular number format in the cell that contains the formula.

Answer (score 0):

Substract the two dates and you will have all the information you need, the integer part is the number of days, the decimal part gives you the hours.

```
    Diff=Now()-B3
    MYDAYS=Truncate(Diff)
    MYHOURS=truncate((Diff-Days)*24)
```